# From Jupyter notebook using R to html with collapsible code cells possibly via (R)MarkDown

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, r-markdown, markdown, knitr

I am using jupyter notebooks and R without problems. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to collapse code cells by default (the ultimate aim is to send stakeholders html with collapsed code cells). Hence, I thought I use (R)Markdown. Here something like this at the beginning allows for code to be collapsed by default:

```
---
title: "1984"
author: "George Orwell"
date: "1948"
output:
 html_document:
    code_folding: hide
    theme: lumen
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    toc_float: yes
---
```

The steps I tried are this:

(1) Download notebook as markdown (file extension .md)
(2) Rename file extension to .rmd
(3) Open in Visual Studio (in my case with [Markdown Editor plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor))

The problem I have, is that when I download the .md file it creates entries like this:

```
![png](output_15_0.png)
```

which do not appear to work when the html is generated.

Can I somehow generate html from my notebook with collapsed code cells? Happy to use knitr etc.

PS:

To add to this, I get:

```
File output_15_0.png not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
```

Maybe I can add the resource path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. All I had to do is use an absolute path. So I replaced:

```
![png](output_15_0.png)
```

with:

```
![png](C:/Repos/SomeGreatSolution/SomeGreatProject/output_15_0.png)
```